# Prove function do not satisfy Lipschitz condition

Tags: lipschitz-functions

How to show that for function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto\mathbb{R}$  $f(\mathbf x)=||\mathbf x||^{3/2}$,

the Lipschitz condition $||\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)||\le L||x-y||$ for all $x,\, y$ is not satisfied for any $L$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that
\begin{align}
\nabla f(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{3}{2}\frac{\mathbf{x}}{\sqrt{\left\|\mathbf{x} \right\|}}
\end{align}
Take $\mathbf{y} = - \mathbf{x}$. Then
\begin{align}
\left\|\nabla f(\mathbf{x}) - \nabla f(\mathbf{y}) \right\| = 3\sqrt{\left\| \mathbf{x}\right\|}
\end{align}
Suppose there was an $L$ such that the inequality held. Then 
\begin{align}
3\sqrt{\left\| \mathbf{x}\right\|} \le 2L \left\|\mathbf{x}\right\|
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align}
L \ge \frac{2}{3\sqrt{\left\|\mathbf{x}\right\|}}.
\end{align}
But as $\left\|\mathbf{x}\right\| \to 0$ . . . whoops.